# Decode QR code image using zxing library in Android

Tags: android, qr-code, zxing

In my application I'm using the zxing library for QR decoding QR code images stored in the Android device. I would like to know how to convert Bitmap to BinaryImage to be decoded. I have found similar questions but none could solve my problem. Please help.

Comment: can u pls share how u done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look in the project code, but under `androidtest/`. There's a class called `RGBLuminanceSource` that does this.

Comment: Thank you Sean. Let me try it out.

Comment: captureActivity capture QR code image from camera and after decoding it, it shows results according to type of data stored in QR code. e.g. if website URL is encoded in QR code, the result screen will have a button to open that URL and likevise.

I need to read image from SD card, decode it and handle the output in the same manner zxing does in case of decoding via captureActivity.

What do I need to do after getting output in "Result result"?

Answer (score 2):

This is the way:

```
            int width = bitmap.getWidth(), height = bitmap.getHeight();
            int[] pixels = new int[width * height];
            bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
            bitmap.recycle();
            bitmap = null;
            RGBLuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(width, height, pixels);
            BinaryBitmap bBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
BinaryBitmap binaryBitmap=new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(new RGBLuminanceSource(bitmap));
```

Comment: I am unable to find RGBLuminanceSource Class :-(

Comment: It is included in the zxing library, double check it.